# wkhtmltopdf not converting html to pdf

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

wkhtmltopdf is an open source (LGPLv3) command line tools to render HTML into PDF. You can find more information about wkhtmltopdf from [here](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/)

wkhtmltopdf is not working if input file name has special characters.

Let me put an example to clear the scienerio

Below code is working fine

```
shell_exec('wkhtmltopdf http://example.com/docs/Export_import_data_masters.html test.pdf');
```

But below code is not working if url have brackets in file name

```
shell_exec('wkhtmltopdf http://example.com/docs/Export_(import_data)_masters.html test.pdf');
```

It fails to create pdf from url if url has special characters in the file name.

Hope i am able to clear the question.

**NOTE**: File Link is provided by the third party so i can't change the file name or file path.

Comment: Yes, you can change the file name - download the file using `file_get_contents()` and save it into a file with a simple name. You can then run the exec command without any difficulties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. The second URL is actually invalid. You remember the saying? "Garbage in, garbage out"? Brackets are not amongst the characters allowed in URLs, you have to escape them to form a valid URL:

   http://example.com/docs/Export_%28import_data%29_masters.html
2. You have to consider that a command you execute in such manner will be interpreted by the shell that is invoked by the `exec()` call. Shells interpret the input they process, especially control characters. So you might have to put quote chars around a URL argument or escape some characters to make things work.

Comment: yes, its' working. Thank you for reminding me a basic thing.